# Overflow text in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a long string of a file path that has no spaces. For example:

This is displayed in a `table`, something like:

```
<td>
    /thisisthetopfolder/thisisthebottomfolder/thisisthefile.html
</td>
```

However, the text does not overflow onto the next line, it is just chopped off/truncated at the end of the table cell's width. I cannot increase the table or table cell's width. Is there a way to force-overflow the text in a table cell so it doesn't cut off?

It looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------
| /thisisthetopfolder/thisi | other info  |
------------------------------------------
```

And it needs to look like this:

```
------------------------------------------
| /thisisthetopfolder/thisi  |            |
|  sthebottomfolder/thisisth |            |
|  efile.html                | other info |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you played with the [`overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS rule:

```
td {
    word-break:break-word;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j8TzJ/)**

The [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-break) CSS property is used to specify how (or if) to break lines within words.